# wp_query pagination links producing 404

Tags: wp-query, loop, pagination

I've searched thousands of related posts and can't seem to get the pagination to work on this loop.

As soon as i click next page i get a 404

```
//get the search term
if (!empty($_GET["s"])){
$s = $_GET["s"];

//the search form will have an input value of "Search..." if nothing has been selected. We need to clear 
if ($s=="Search..."){
    $s='';
}
}

$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$limit = 10;
     $args = array(
    //the user inputed search term
    's' => $s,
    'post_type' => 'schools',   
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'paged' => $paged,
    //we use tax_query here to query the schools custom taxonomy. 
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            //name of school categories (custom taxonomy)
            'taxonomy' => 'school_category',
            //we are going to search by matching category ids
            'field' => 'id',
            //the array we created that contains all the category ids to be searched
            'terms' => $category_and,
            //we want to make sure only posts in all of the categories selected are shown.
            'operator' => 'AND'
        ),
        array(
            //name of school categories (custom taxonomy)
            'taxonomy' => 'school_moi',
            //we are going to search by matching category ids
            'field' => 'id',
            //the array we created that contains all the category ids to be searched
            'terms' => $category_MOI,
            //we want to make sure only posts in all of the categories selected are shown.
            'operator' => 'AND'
        ),
        array(
            //name of school categories (custom taxonomy)
            'taxonomy' => 'school_curriculum',
            //we are going to search by matching category ids
            'field' => 'id',
            //the array we created that contains all the category ids to be searched
            'terms' => $category_cur,
            //we want to make sure only posts in all of the categories selected are shown.
            'operator' => 'AND'
        )

    )

);

//The new query with our arguements
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );

woo_loop_before();

if ($wp_query->have_posts()) { $count = 0;

$title_before = '<h1 class="archive_header">';
$title_after = '</h1>';

//echo $title_before . sprintf( __( 'Search results for &quot;%s&quot;', 'woothemes' ), get_search_query() ) . $title_after;    
    ?>

<div class="fix"></div>

<?php
    //Make sure the search results take into account the categories chosen on the seach bar

    while ($wp_query->have_posts()) {$wp_query->the_post(); $count++;

        if (get_option('woo_woo_tumblog_switch') == 'true') { $is_tumblog = woo_tumblog_test(); } else { $is_tumblog = false; }

        woo_get_template_part( 'content', 'search' );

    } // End WHILE Loop



    next_posts_link('&laquo; Next');
    previous_posts_link('Previous &raquo;');

    //wp_reset_postdata();

  } else {
get_template_part( 'content', 'noposts' );
  } // End IF Statement


  woo_loop_after();
```

I have the **blog pages show at most option** set to 1.

Help would be really appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i think that you need to use `wp_reset_query();` before `woo_loop_after();`

Comment: nope, i had reset query at the bottom of the page. Tried moving it as per your suggestion, but no luck.

Comment: please update your question with last code you tried